# Doubt of geometric notation about vertices and polygons

Tags: geometry, notation

If ABCD is a quadrilateral, does this notation imply that vertex B is connected with vertex A and with vertex C?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: What else could it be ?

Comment: I was just asking to make sure because I wasn't able to find a clarification. Maybe order didn't matter